# How can I install a python .egg file

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to install twisted on python 2.6 and it seems that the Zop interface is missing.
Also it seems that it is a `.egg` file.  I downloaded this `.egg` file, now how can I install it?

Answer (score 4):

Install [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/), which includes [`pip`](http://pip.openplans.org/). Then you can simply run:

```
pip install twisted
```

`pip` will handle installing the zope.interface.

### Instructions for installing virtualenv and pip on OS X

This is how I installed `virtualenv` and `pip` on OS X:

```
curl -O http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
sudo python ez_setup.py
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

I also like to use [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/) with `virtualenv`, so I installed it using:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

### Instructions for installing Twisted in a virtualenv

Now to create a new virtual environment and install Twisted, I simply issue:

```
mkvirtualenv twisted-env
pip install twisted
```

Comment: easy_install also handles them

Comment: True, but pip is now recommended in favor of using easy_install. http://s3.pixane.com/pip_distribute.png

Comment: You can also do it the other way round: `virtualenv` automatically installs `pip`, so you can just download `virtualenv`.

Comment: @Daniel. You are correct. You don't have to install `pip` in your global site-packages if you install `virtualenv`. However, `pip`, `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper`, and `distribute` are the four packages that I don't mind having in the global site-packages. Everything else I install inside a `virtualenv`.

Comment: NO.  NEVER EVER do 'sudo python setup.py install' whatever.  Write a ~/.pydistutils.cfg that puts your pip installation into ~/.local or something.  Especially files named 'ez_setup.py' tend to suck down newer versions of things like setuptools and easy_install, which can potentially break other things on your operating system.

Comment: @Glyph — I'm interested in learning more of why you recommend I not install `pip` using `ez_setup.py`. I created a new [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4324558/), and am hoping that you'll weigh in there.