# Confusing Python install in user local (virtualenv, pip, distribute)

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv, pip, distribute

I tried to install python below way. But this did not work.
This take "error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH".

[What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python/4325047#4325047)

Make directory

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.python
```

Add .bashrc

```
#Use local python
export PATH=$HOME/.python/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.python
```

Create a file ~/.pydistutils.cfg

```
[install]
prefix=~/.python
```

Get install script

```
$ cd ~/src
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
```

Execute and Error

```
$ python ./distribute_setup.py
Extracting in /tmp/tmpsT2kdA
Now working in /tmp/tmpsT2kdA/distribute-0.6.15
Installing Distribute
Before install bootstrap.
Scanning installed packages
No setuptools distribution foundrunning install
Checking .pth file support in /home/sane/.python/lib/python2.6/site-packages//usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST FAILED: /home/sane/.python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH
You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
/home/sane/.python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:
'/home/sane/.python'
Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:
* You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is 
on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files
* You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment 
variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run 
Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)
* You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by 
using one of the approaches described here:
http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
```

My environment('sane' is my unix user name.)

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.4
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.34.8-68.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 17 15:03:58 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choice pythonbrew.
I can use multiple Pythons in my home directory by this.
It's a great job.

utahta/pythonbrew - GitHub https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew

Comment: "This project is no longer under active development. You are encouraged to try out [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) instead." - pythonbrew's README

Answer (score 0):

Usually I installed distributed/easy_install aka setuptools in my global Python installation together with virtualenv. From this point on I can created dedicated virtualalized environments using

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages name-of-environment
```

Really no idea why to fiddle around with PYTHONPATH here.

Adding /path/to/name-of-environment/bin to $PATH is good enough for adding the virtualized
Python to your $PATH. You don't need any else.