# Installing multiple main and bit versions of Python

Tags: python, windows-7, installation

What would be the best way/order to install both 32 and 64 bit versions of Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 if I want **64 bit Python 3.3** to be the default when I open *.py* files?

I already have the 32 bit version of each installed, with defaults set to Python 3.3.

---

If it is fine to just rename the directory of my currently installed version, will *python27.dll* and programmes using it (or *python33.dll*) continue to work? This library gets installed to *%WINDIR%\System32* and/or *%WINDIR%\SysWoW64* by the python installer.

---

Thanks for your answers, here is what I did:

1. Uninstalled Python 3.3 (This left 2 files)

   - *C:\Python33\Lib\lib2to3\Grammar3.3.0.final.0.pickle*
   - *C:\Python33\Lib\lib2to3\PatternGrammar3.3.0.final.0.pickle*
2. Uninstalled Python 2.7
3. Installed Python 2.7 x86 *(without register extensions)*

   - `C:\Python\27_32\`
4. Installed Python 2.7 x86-64 *(without register extensions)*

   - `C:\Python\27\`
5. Installed Python 3.3 x86 *(without register extensions)*

   - `C:\Python\33_32\`
6. Installed Python 3.3 x86-64 *(with default register extensions)*

   - `C:\Python\33\`
7. Deleted *C:\Python33*

   - CCleaner'd installer reference issues to this location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installer typically has an option for "Set file associations" that handles that, and I think it's on by default, which means that the most-recently-installed one will handle double-clicking .py files.  So install 64-bit Python 3.3 last and it should work.  I just did this a few days ago with 32- and 64-bit version of 2.7 and it seems to work fine.

I wouldn't rename your existing directory, though.  You should install each version of Python in its own directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) launcher and configure it to launch your preferred version of Python. A copy comes with all versions of Python 3.3, or you can install it separately.

To elaborate:

Rather than launching Python by typing `python` in a shell, run `py.exe` (this should also be the default action for double clicking on a Python file if the most recently installed version is Python 3.3 or later). `py.exe` is a helper program that searches for and locates an appropriate version of Python on your system.

You can edit an `.ini` file in various locations to specify the default version, or your Python scripts can specify the version they expect to be run with (using a "shebang" line, as described in the PEP). So you can set your system default to be 64-bit Python 3.3, while also allowing individual scripts to use other versions on demand.

Comment: This looks interesting but I couldn't find any info on how it could tell the difference between bit-versions unless I edited the `.ini`, but then it would mean the shebang lines wouldn't work for anyone else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A shebang line of `#!python` (or for Unix compatibility, `#!/usr/bin/python`) will always launch the highest version of Python 2 available, with a 64 bit version preferred if both 32 and 64-bit are available for that version. You can use `#!python3` to request Python 3, or `#!python3.2` to explicitly require Python 3.2, even if 3.3 is available. You an use `#!python2.6-32` if your script will only run on Python 2.6 32-bit. You only need to modify the `.ini` file if you want to modify the defaults (to prefer Python 3 over 2, or 3.2 over 3.3, for instance).

Comment: Ah, I only saw the command line switch section for choosing 32 bit. Thanks! This will most likely be useful for me.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a virtualenv for each version (2.7/3.2) or flavor (32-bit/64-bit) of python you want to install. Essentially, a virtualenv is a sandbox for your installation, which doesn't leak through into other sandboxes.

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) explains how to make virtualenvs