# Trouble importing Python modules on Ninja IDE

Tags: python, ide, module

I have been trying to import modules into Ninja IDE for python. These are modules that I have working on the terminal (numpy, scipy, scitools, matplotlib, and mpl_toolkits), but will not run correctly in Ninja.

First I was only getting the message `No module named ____`. I checked `sys.path` and found that the path was within the application

`/Applications/Ninja IDE.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7`   was a typical path. I tried changing the path,but it doesn't seem to do anything to `sys.path` even after restarting the ide.

But I wanted the path to refer to where the modules are stored (which is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`). I was able to get numpy and scipy to work as well as parts of mpl_toolkits by adding the contents of my path to the folders that `sys.path` gave. However, I still can't get fully functioning modules within the ninja ide interpreter.  I'll give some examples below of what happens when I import certain modules.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Ninja IDE.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sysconfig

import mpl_toolkits

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Ninja IDE.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Ninja IDE.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Ninja IDE.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

Thanks for the help. I apologize, I am very new to programming, but I did put in about a day and a half of research before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange as the `sysconfig` module is a part of Python 2.7 standard library. 
Are you sure that Ninja is using the right Python version? Try running:

```
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

from Ninja, to see which Python version it is actually using.

Comment: Hmm, it uses version 2.7.2, and my terminal version is 2.7.3. That shouldn't really make a huge difference should it? I was under the impression that this stuff worked pretty seamlessly as long it was 2.7.x.

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't. But there is definitely something wrong (e.g. you were expecting 2.7.3 instead of 2.7.2, weren't you?).

Comment: Well not necessarily. All of my modules are specific for python 2.7 and mac OS X lion. There must be a way to run the same modules in your ide that you run on the terminal without actively changing file locations.

Comment: I have been confused by this problem some time too. From the reply above, I also found that my python version in Mac OS X is 2.7.1, but from ninja-ide, I got the version 2.7.2.  It is really strange. And I tried to set the python path in ninja-ide. But it can not work. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few months old, but I wanted to post my solution in case others find it useful. I had a very similar problem, and had a lot of trouble finding a quick workable solution anywhere.

My somewhat roundabout solution was to simply create a virtualenv folder with the version of numpy I wanted, and then pointed the "virtualenv" property for NinjaIDE project to that folder. I restarted NinjaIDE and boom, instantly worked.

To set the virtualenv property for your project via the GUI, go to the Project menu:

```
Project > Open Project Properties > Project Execution,
```

and you should see a variable called "Virtualenv Folder". Point that to the folder for your virtualenv, and it should work. (May need to restart NinjaIDE.) This worked for me, NinjaIDE version 2.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.

One quick note: I actually didn't use virtualenv exactly -- I had to use a  "[conda env](http://docs.continuum.io/conda/examples/create.html)," since I am using the Anaconda distribution, and apparently it is not well-tested with virtualenv yet. (I actually got a warning when I went to easy_install virtualenv. Hadn't seen that before.)

Either way, this stackoverflow question has some nice pointers to virtualenv tutorials: [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem trying to import a module from `/home/paul/lib/python` using the console of the Ninja-IDE. I found out that `/home/paul/lib/python` didn't appear in `syspath` when checking in the console of the Ninja-IDE. But it did in the terminal!

By starting the Ninja-IDE from the terminal, `/home/paul/lib/python` *was* in `syspath` when checking in the console of the Ninja-IDE. I was now able to import the module I needed.

I hope this might be of some help. If not to ebris1 than maybe to others.