# Python Package and module version management

Tags: python, version-control, python-import

I plan to develop a medium scale web application (with lot of back-end work) using multiple packages (internal and external), since it's my first experience with such scale, can I get some advice on:

1. How to ensure that all dependencies are satisfied (no required package/module is missing, packages were imported from right location etc.)
2. How to manage versions of packages/modules. I want to be able to introduce new versions of packages/modules with minimal code changes in other connected packages/modules.

Please let me know if there is a tool that can be of help in this.
If there is any other challenge (which I may not even be aware of) that comes in managing code with this scale  then please caution me and provide ways to resolve it.

What I know currently (and think that it may help in code management):

- `__all__` to define exportable modules.
- Use of preceding single underscore to prevent modules from getting imported
- `__init__.py` to manage imports at package level (so when I do `import package_name` then `__init__.py` can centrally control other imports)
- PEP 328 to manage relative imports, importlib and other such stuff around importing.
- I suppose some of the 3rd party packages also define `__version__` or `VERSION` variable to check the version at runtime, but I am not sure if I can rely on it.

If there are books, blogs etc. that can help then please let me know.

EDIT: I am not sure if this type of question fits here on SO. If not then I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to ensure that all dependencies are satisfied (no required package/module is missing, packages were imported from right location etc.)

Use a [virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) and [freeze](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-freeze) the packages with [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) to a [requirements](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) file:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.31
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Basically, use virtualenv, distribute and pip whenever you have some code that'll need a module installed.

To install packages according to the version specified in your `requirements.txt`:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks timss. I use virtualenv, let me read further to see if freeze can help manage versions of packages and ease introduction/testing of new ones. I want to understand how we manage versions of our own packages, do we define version variable, or we create separate packages like chat01 chat02. What if I have import package_name and now I want to try an updated package (think of it as writing versioned REST APIs and managing them)

Comment: @AccEnq Freeze can help you manage versions, because you can later install packages with the version in `requirements.txt` with pip (updated answer). I'm not sure how you would solve it with personal packages, but pip can install from local files aswell.