# Using old version of numpy even with a newer version installed

Tags: python, numpy

I have used easy_install to install numpy to install numpy 1.7.1, but when I check my version in python:

```
python -c "import numpy; print numpy.version.version"
```

It says 1.6.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I advise you to use a [virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) if you want to work with specific versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, you have installed numpy from a debian repository or a pip installation with other parameters. Use

```
python -c 'import os,numpy;print(numpy.__file__)'
```

to find out where the rogue numpy version lies. While you can just delete this directory, you can also ask your package manager what package the file belongs to. Again, on a debian system:

```
$ python -c 'import numpy;print(numpy.__file__)'
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/__init__.pyc
$ readlink -f /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/__init__.py
/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/__init__.py
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/pyshared/numpy/__init__.py
python-numpy: /usr/share/pyshared/numpy/__init__.py
$ sudo apt-get remove python-numpy
```

Comment: Using the numpy.__file__ helped me tracked down where the numpy install was and I was able to do the rest myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

sudo easy_install -U numpy

...after many tries, the code above worked for me, finally!