# Nltk import problems

Tags: python, nltk, importerror

I can import ntlk and the pos_tag in the python shell just fine like so.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
```

But when I need to write a script like

```
import nltk
from nltk import pos_tag
```

I get a traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mynltkfile.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk import pos_tag
File "/Users/jacksongeller/Desktop/nltktest/mynltkfile.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk import pos_tag
ImportError: cannot import name pos_tag
```

I have already done nltk.download() and have downloaded everything.
I have also piped numpy

Also if I just import nltk from a script, I get the same traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mynltkfile.py", line 1, in <module>
import nltk
File "/Users/jacksongeller/Desktop/nltktest/mynltkfile.py", line 1, in <module>
from nltk import pos_tag
ImportError: cannot import name pos_tag
```

Am I missing a file? If so where should it go?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the interpreter, type

```
import nltk
import sys
print(nltk)
print(sys.executable)
```

and then create a script with the same contents and run

```
python script.py
```

Please post the output.

Comment: The interpreter
>>> print(nltk)
<module 'nltk' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.pyc'>
>>> print(sys.executable)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Comment: And what about the output when run from a script?

Comment: the script
`code`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Users/jacksongeller/Desktop/nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name pos_tag

Comment: I believe it had something to do with the directory, i tried placing the script above in my home directory where nltk is stored, and that worked fine.

Comment: Yes, you do have two versions of `nltk` installed. One in `/Library/Python2.7/site-packages` and another in `/Users/jacksongeller/Desktop`.

Comment: Do you need both? If you do, you should use [virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5844869/190597) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/dhellmann/virtualenvwrapper). If not, you should delete the one you do not need so Python will always find the same `nltk` package.

Comment: So I deleted both directories of the nltk data and did the following command sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all.  It all works now thanks