# Why does `import word_tokenize` from NLTK works in the interpreter but not in my script?

Tags: python, import, namespaces, nlp, nltk

I am trying to tokenize a sentence using nltk. when i do it through python shell i get the correct answer.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = "Mohanlal made his acting debut in Thiranottam (1978), but the film got released only after 25 years due to censorship issues."
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['Mohanlal', 'made', 'his', 'acting', 'debut', 'in', 'Thiranottam', '(', '1978', ')', ',', 'but', 'the', 'film', 'got', 'released', 'only', 'after', '25', 'years', 'due', 'to', 'censorship', 'issues', '.']
```

But when i write the same code in a file and try to run it i got the following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
    from nltk.util import ngrams
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/util.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 55, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/home/gadheyan/Project/Codes/tokenize.py", line 2, in <module>
    from nltk import word_tokenize
ImportError: cannot import name word_tokenize
```

Here's the code that i run.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

sentence = "Mohanlal made his acting debut in Thiranottam (1978), but the film got released only after 25 years due to censorship issues."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print tokens
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE that might be running a different version of Python?

Comment: Check out this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155704/python-failed-to-import-nltk-but-works-with

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

It's a naming problem, see [Python failed to `import nltk` in my script but works in the interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155704/python-failed-to-import-nltk-but-works-with)

Rename your file to `my_tokenize.py` instead of `tokenize.py`, i.e.

```
$ mv /home/gadheyan/Project/Codes/tokenize.py /home/gadheyan/Project/Codes/my_tokenize.py
$ python my_tokenize.py
```

---

**In long:**

From your traceback, you see:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/home/gadheyan/Project/Codes/tokenize.py", line 2, in <module>
    from nltk import word_tokenize
```

In NLTK, there is a package call `nltk.tokenize` where  `nltk.word_tokenize` resides, http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html

So when you have your script name as `tokenize.py` and when you call `nltk.word_tokenize` and when it goes into the nltk and tries to import `nltk.tokenize`, it imports your script (`/home/gadheyan/Project/Codes/tokenize.py`) instead of `nltk.tokenize` since [`inspect.py`](https://pymotw.com/2/inspect/) uses the local [namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

---

**BTW**

Redundant namespaces would still work in python but it's better to keep your namespaces and global variables clean, i.e. use this:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> sent = 'this is a foo bar sentence'
>>> word_tokenize(sent)
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence']
>>> exit()
```

Or this:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> sent = 'this is a foo bar sentence'
>>> nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence']
>>> exit()
```

But try to avoid this (although it still works regardless):

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> sent = 'this is a foo bar sentence'
>>> word_tokenize(sent)
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence']
>>> nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence']
>>> exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! I was trying to understand why people import nltk and then continue importing subpackages ugh, I knew it didn't seem right