# ImportError : No module named 'nltk.chunk.named.entity' in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, nltk, pyinstaller, named-entity-recognition

Having a runtime exception when runninga a packaged named entity recognition code using python nltk library. Pyinstaller has been used for making the .exe file. Python 3.5 with Anaconda is installed in the machine.

```
ImportError : No module named 'nltk.chunk.named.entity'. Failed to execute script
```

The following code has been used in NER_1.py file.

```
#Code modificaiton for standalone python run - PythonInstaller version
#importing libraries
import nltk
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
import re 
import os
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer


#Reading the text from console
print("Enter the text - ")
raw = sys.stdin.readline()


sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(raw)  #split in to sentances
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences] #split in to words
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences] #tag sentences with NN, NNP, etc
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
        if t.label() == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names


entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))


#Check if the output is null  
if not entity_names:
    print("List is empty")
    entity_names.append("NullNER")

# Print unique entity names
print (set(entity_names))

input("Press any key to exit...")
```

Comment: What did you name your python script or your project directory? Was it `nltk.py` or `nltk/`?

Comment: your code is correct, it is giving me expected output.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155704/python-failed-to-import-nltk-in-my-script-but-works-in-the-interpreter

Comment: @alvas I've names my script as NER_1.py. So the problem is not with the name or the directory.

Comment: @WasiAhmad the code runs well on the interpreter. The error occurs when packaging it with Pyinstaller.

Comment: It's seems like an error from the PyInstaller upstream https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1099 =( Maybe PyInstaller dev can help with it.