# How to choose which version of python runs from terminal?

Tags: python, unix

I have a few different versions of python on my computer. How do I choose which one is run from my terminal when I type `python` into the prompt?

Answer (score 17):

Use `which` to see where your python command resides. Then use `ls -l` to find out where it *really* is. Then link the one you want instead. Note that the other installed versions are usually all available by their respective names.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 18  2013 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7         /usr/bin/python2-config
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7-config  /usr/bin/python-config
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

Note that this changes which Python version **all programs for all users on your computer will probably use**! If you only want to change it for yourself. You can alias it by adding a `alias python='/usr/bin/python2'` line (with `python2` replaced by the version you want) to `~/.bashrc` in linux or `~/.bash_profile` in Mac. (You'll need to restart your terminal session in this case.)

Comment: I don't think you ever want to link python versions like that. See the other answers. I wish I could downvote

Answer (score 11):

You should have multiple executables for every python version you have. For example, if I type `python` and hit tab, I see:

```
$ python
python             python2.5-config   python2.7-config   python3.3          python3.3m-config  pythonw2.7         pythonw3.3-32      
python-config      python2.6          python3            python3.3-32       pythonw            pythonw3           
python2            python2.6-config   python3-32         python3.3-config   pythonw2.5         pythonw3-32        
python2.5          python2.7          python3-config     python3.3m         pythonw2.6         pythonw3.3
```

So, if, for example, I want python 2.5 version - I run `python2.5`.

Also, take a look at [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) - it's much easier to manage and switch between multiple python environments with it.

Also see:

- [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)
- [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 11):

py -3 or py -2 etc to choose between versions. Even 32/64 bit versions can be differentiated:

```
py -2 
py -3.7-32
py -3.7-64
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel

Answer (score 4):

To choose which version of python is run when you type 'python' into a terminal, you may want to try using an alias.

For example:

```
alias python='python2.7'
```

Would make python2.7 execute when you type 'python' into your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

One option is `update-alternatives`:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.11   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.11   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.11 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode
$ python3 -V
Python 3.11.0rc1
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.11   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.11   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.10 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in manual mode
$ python3 -V
Python 3.10.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [envirius (universal virtual environments manager)](https://github.com/ekalinin/envirius), which allows to compile any version of python.
Moreover, it allows to create environments with mixed languages.