# Install astLib python module without root access

Tags: python, installation

However my school's computer lab put python together, astLib is not a module it contains. I want to install it in/through my home directory. Im very unfamiliar with the use of unix commands.(all I know how to do is change directory, and open python.) I have a website that tries to explain how to do it, but i dont know what to type into my directory, and i dont know how to do the second step which is to add something into .bashrc. Ive seen one stackoverflow question, in which the user had a similar problem, but was told to ask an admin. The lab's admin is no longer on the faculty, and they are looking into a replacement sometime in the next year.

Here is the link: http://astlib.sourceforge.net/?q=install0.3

I am very new to programing, so the instructions on that link were unclear to me.
My question is, what do i have to type into my command prompt, and how do i add the code shown in the link to .bashrc?

Edit: Ok, so now I learned how to go into the .bashrc file, and I copy/paste the line of code into there. I ran the command throught the command prompt, but i get an error message

error: package directory 'astLib' does not exist

Did I put the downloaded file in the wrong directory? (im pretty sure its in my home directory) Did I put the .bashrc code in the wrong place?(i just put it on the bottom of the code)

Answer (score 1):

<s>If you want to install astLib as system module, I recomend that you install it by `pip install` way</s>

If you don't want to, you should install virtualenv, create you own environment and then install it there.

Maybe this link helps you to install virtualenv: [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)

Edit: I've re-read the question and you have only the virtualenv's option