# How do I deploy a python application to an external server?

Tags: python, deployment, packaging

I have written a python script on my local laptop which uses several third party packages. I now want to run my script regularly (via a cron job) on an external server.

The external server most likely does not have all the dependencies installed, is there is a way to package and deploy my python script and dependencies in order to ensure that it will run?

I have already tried to package the script as an exe, but failed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what kind of third party packages you have, but for those that were installed with pip, you can do this in your dev environment:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And then you can install these packages in your production environment:

```
$ pip install requirements.txt
```

Ideally, you will already have a virtualenv on your production box. If not, it may be well worth reading about these before deploying your script.

Comment: what is a virtualenv? i know, i can google, but i think you could recommend any good introductory reads about virtualenv. thanks!

Comment: @beta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial

Comment: by the way, how i did it now: i just copied the script on my external server, and downloaded all the requirements/dependencies i needed. then created a cronjob and that's it. if i will deploy more python projects on this external server, i will surely check out virtualenv!

Answer (score -1):

Just turn your computer into a server. Simply set up your router for port forwarding so that your server's content's will display when the router's IP is entered. You can of course purchase a DNS domain to give that IP a human readable URL.

Comment: that's not really feasible for me. i don't want my laptop to run 24/7. i have access to real servers and want to make use of them. however, they run on different OS, etc... so i am thinking of an efficient way to deploy the python script, which i developed on my laptop on these external servers.. there must be a way, i'm sure.

Comment: Perhps you can use SSH to connect to these servers and install Python and the other frameworks.