# Why are different versions of numpy and scipy installed on two boxes

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy

I have just ran the following command on two Ubuntu boxes:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy
```

When I ran pip freeze on both machines, I saw that different versions were installed:

```
numpy==1.6.1
scipy==0.9.0

numpy==1.9.1
scipy==0.15.1
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machines are likely using different `apt` repositories. This is the case, for example, if they are running different versions of Ubuntu.

A better approach would be to create a [virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) and install the latest packages using `pip`, rather than using your system's package manager.

Comment: I tried that - pip install will not install scipy in my virtualenv.

Comment: @AlexC Well that's a different question :). You're likely experiencing compilation errors because you don't have your build tools setup properly, or are missing the required header files / libraries. I'd suggest you skip all of that and download something like the [Anaconda python](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) distribution. If that doesn't work, then open a new question with a detailed description of your problem.