# How to make custom python site-packages?

Tags: python, python-2.7

We are building python 2.7.9 based test encryption server on "Windows" and need to install n number of python packages using pip/python setup.py install.

Problem is, we are 4-5 python learner. If anyone adds new feature then he has to inform everyone and update build machine with new python package.

Is there any where we can specify python packages to install into custom site-packages and later, check-ins site-packages into github and next git pull every one get package and start using it?

I could not find any way, please provide me some pointer where I can start looking it.

Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 2):

You should be using VirtualEnv for that - this question and its answers:  [Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) have good pointers on where to start.