# How to install packages inside a project in python using command line on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, package, pip

**Environment:**

> Windows 10 64bit
>   Python 3.5.1 32bit
>   Visual Studio Code

**What I know**

- `pip install xxxx` install globally
- Using Pycharm install via settings

**Problem**

How can I install a package *inside* a project using the command line on Windows? I looked through the documents, there is something called a `VirtualEnv`, but I don't get this command in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install virtualenv using pip.

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

Once installed, you can refer this guide to get started with virtualenv.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 0):

VirtualEnv is your best bet. The answers in the following post can help you get familiar with VirtualEnv.
[Comprehensive beginner's virtualenv tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)

To run it on Windows, have a look at this link:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Comment: Also refer to the following links:
http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/

http://pymote.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html

Answer (score 0):

`venv` comes with Python. I am not sure what advantages there are to the addon virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=venv#module-venv