# pgadmin4 - New install not working

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I downloaded the `postgresql-9.6.0-1-linux-x64.run` package and ran through the installer on **ubuntu 16.04**. **Postgres** is working fine. I am trying to use the **pgadmin4** package that was included with this installer. I created a site in Apache per the instructions.

This is the error I am getting in the server.log file in Apache. Not sure how to fix this.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/pgAdmin4/web/pgAdmin4.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
     from pgAdmin4 import app as application

File "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/pgAdmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 24, in <module>
     from pgadmin import create_app

File "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/pgAdmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>

  from flask_babel import Babel, gettext

ImportError: No module named flask_babel
```

Comment: You can [use Docker for this purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593274/776546) and not waste time in any funny configurations.

Answer (score 3):

This error message shows that your environment is missing a package called `flask_babel`. To install it, switch to the virtualenv your webserver uses and install it with this command:

```
pip install flask_babel
```

If you are not using any virtual environment for your python scripts, you have to prepend `sudo` to the command. But you should really [consider using a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial) for your projects.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using virtualenv to run pgAdmin4 then you need to activate it first,
Refer Apache mine wsgi file.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flask_babel is one of the dependencies of pgAdmin4, and there will be others.

You may find it easier to use a Python Wheel installer, which you can find here:
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/

With this distribution, simply execute:

```
pip install ./pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

And then configure the application as indicated on the website.

If you run this command in a virtual environment, the dependencies will be installed in this environment.

If you want to run on an Apache server, this installation will produce a .wsgi file in the site-packages folder of your python installation.

Answer (score 0):

fixed near issues with:

```
pip install flask_babel
pip3 install flask_babelex
```

mine were:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/setup.py", line 31, in 
<module>
    from pgadmin import create_app
  File "/media/netunit/storageII/my_env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flask_babelex import Babel, gettext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_babelex'
```