# Error trying to run pgAdmin4

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin-4

I've installed postgresql 9.6 (using suggested linux installer) which comes with pgAdmin4, but getting a few errors.

First, I had to change the folder name from "pgAdmin 4" (note the extra space) to "pgAdmin4" to avoid "file not found error".

Then I run `sudo python pgAdmin4.py` and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../../pgAdmin4.py", line 24, in <module>
      from pgadmin import create_app
   File "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/pgAdmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
      from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I tried following this related question:
[Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)
 -- managed to installed flask on virtualenv.

But then I started getting other flask related modules that are missing: flask_babel, flask_login, flask_security. I installed all of them using pip, but then I got an error on missing module `htmlmin.minify` which I can't seems to able to install.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../pgAdmin4.py", line 24, in <module>
      from pgadmin import create_app
   File "/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/pgAdmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from htmlmin.minify import html_minify
ImportError: No module named htmlmin.minify
```

I also exported PYTHONPATH to the one on flask, as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACCA4P0jygzKLHUXz%3DS%2By-P%2B3QdW2t%2BQBG-2%2BWbf5GvE4-E53g@mail.gmail.com), still getting the same error.

So, anyone have an idea how to make pgAdmin4 work on ubuntu environemt?

Comment: Have you installed virtualenv? Are you trying to do everything from inside the virtualenv?

Comment: I installed virtualenv but it might be that I'm not actually running from within that virtual env? how do I make sure?

Comment: You need to activate the virtualenv by running `. venv/bin/activate` where venv is the result of `virtualenv venv`. Insted dot, you can use command `source`.

Comment: Yes I run the environment, which caused the terminal to show prompt starting with the env name (flask). Still, getting an error.
I suspect the pip installation was not done on the virtualenv. When I run pip install flask I'm getting an error on permissions, so I run it using sudo, but I think sudo causes it to be installed outside of the virtualenv.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php.

Install the virtualenv by running:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

You also need to install these 2 libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
```

Then:

```
cd ~/bin/
virtualenv pgadmin4
```

I prefer to use the `~/bin/` directory for installing applications.

Then you download the `pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl` or `pgadmin4-1.1-py3-none-any.whl` depending on the python version you use. For this example we use python 2.7.

You download pgadmin4:

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.1/pip/pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

Activate the virtualenv:

```
. ~/bin/pgadmin4/bin/activate
```

After that you will see `(pgadmin4)` in the terminal.

Inside of pgadmin4 run:

```
pip install ./pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

After that you must be able to run pgadmin4:

```
python ~/bin/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

In order to make the running process a bit easier you can create an alias. For instance, in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, add alias in the `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias pgadmin4='. /home/your_username/bin/pgadmin4/bin/activate; /home/your_username/bin/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py'
```

Where `your_username` should be replaced by your real user name.

Then give execute permission, for example, `764` to the `pgAdmin4.py` file in:

```
/home/your_username/bin/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Also you need to edit the `pgAdmin4.py` file and add this line in the very top:

```
#!/home/your_username/bin/pgadmin4/bin/python
```

where `your_username` is your real user name.

This will make sure that you run the application using the required version of python and include all necessary dependencies in order to run `pgadmin4`.

Then run `. ~/.bashrc` in order to apply the changes.

So now you can open your terminal and simply type `pgadmin4` in order to run it.

Open your browser and point to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5050
```

One more thing to note - if you need to run `pgadmin4` in desktop mode you need to change `SERVER_MODE` to False in:

```
/home/your_username/bin/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py
```

Otherwise when you visit localhost:5050 it will ask you for your login and password.

**UDPATE:**

As of 2021 (and significantly earlier) a much better option would be to use a preconfigured docker container with pgadmin4 on it. For example, a pgadmin4 docker image can be downloaded from
https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So creating a directory with a virtualenv that you use and then starting it makes sense. What seems strange is that you then need to point to the file location within python 2.7's site packages to start the application.

Doesn't this seem a little convoluted? Is this really the intended workflow that one must follow every time they want to start up PgAdmin4?

Comment: @kuanb, According to the official website https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pip4.php you need to use that path in python 2.7' site packages in order to run pgadmin4. As a workaround I made an alias where I activate the virtualenv and then run the pgadmin4 and it works nicely. I will edit the answer to show how it works.

Comment: @Nurzhan I think you're missing "python" before calling the pgadmin4.py file in your alias definition.

Comment: @newdimension No, you don't need `python` before calling `pgadmin4.py`. `pgadmin4.py` is an executable itself.

Comment: There is a mistake in this line. `wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.1/pip/pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl` no need for pgadmin3 folder. The correct url should be, `https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.1/pip/pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl`

Comment: 2021-03-04 12:11:59 FEHLER 404: Not Found.

Comment: @SteveK There https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/

Comment: For python 3 in 2022 pgadmin4 v1.1 is deprecated you can download new version with below command  wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v6.6/pip/pgadmin4-6.6-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: Thanks for including the link to the docker doc.

Answer (score 12):

After following the documentation on adding PgAdmin 4 to my Fedora 28 failed in every possible way I went with the **Docker** option:

```
mkdir ~/.pgadmin4  # to store config and stuff
docker run -d --rm --network host -v ~/.pgadmin4:/pgadmin thajeztah/pgadmin4
```

Then go to http://localhost:5050 and you are done with it.

See https://github.com/thaJeztah/pgadmin4-docker for more info.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution.  I now have Docker and pgAdmin4 runing on a Chromebook.  For details on Chrombook Docker setup go follow these steps:Install Docker on Chromebook

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

sudo apt update 

 sudo apt install docker-ce

sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER

Answer (score 3):

Please, try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install pgadmin4

sudo python3.5 /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

Comment: and then you have to install every flask extension to your python 3.5 installation

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pgadmin4` is not working anymore as on the date this comment is posted. It gives an error `E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

On debian at least the **web version** is not depending on that `sudo apt install pgadmin4-web`. Know it could be that you need the rich client, but you can consider it as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

for following link -  ERROR 404: Not Found.

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin3/pgadmin4/v1.1/pip/pgadmin4-1.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

use alternate link

```
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.4/pip/pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

also run [reference](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/8761#issuecomment-427549168)

```
pip install pgadmin4-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl -U psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can following command for installation:

## Install for both desktop and web modes:

sudo apt install pgadmin4

## Install for desktop mode only:

sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop

## Install for web mode only:

sudo apt install pgadmin4-web

You can refer to below documentation:
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Answer (score -1):

If you use Windows, try to delete the folder: `%APPDATA%\pgAdmin`