# Python module failed to import

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, pgadmin

I am pretty sure that I am missing something naive. I tried to look up for the solution online but seems like I couldn't find it either.

I am trying to install `pgadmin4` on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. I have installed `miniconda2` following instructions [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html). Then I tried to install `pgadmin4` following instructions [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/).

First I was getting an error:

`ImportError: No module named flask`

when I tried to run

`sudo python ~/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py`

But I was successfully able to `python -c "import flask"` from terminal.

Then I resolved it by installing

`sudo apt-get install python-flask`

But now if I try to run `pgAdmin4.py` it gives me following error:

`ImportError: No module named flask_babel`

and again I am successfully able to import it if I run following command.

`python -c "import flask_babel"`

I am not sure what I am missing, any help would be really appreciated.

**Edit**

Okay, so I removed that error by installing

`sudo apt-get install python-flask-babel` (Thanks to Peter Wood's comment)

Now I am getting another error:

`ImportError: No module named flask_htmlmin`

And I guess I can resolve this too in the same pattern, but my confusion is why those imports works when I do from terminal (inline python or even if I just run python from terminal and import it by myself) and why it doesn't work when I run the script (i.e. `pgAdmin4.py` in this case).

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-flask-babel`

Comment: https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/utopic/python-flask-babel

Comment: Please check the edited post.

Comment: *"my confusion is why those imports work"* - how do you know it works?

Comment: Well, as mentioned when I tried importing any of above mentioned module using inline python script from shell, they worked. But when I try to run python file and if it is trying to import, it fails.

Comment: [`whereis python`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/find-linux-unix-command-location.html)

Comment: Did you try following these steps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260004/error-trying-to-run-pgadmin4

Comment: Also, try this pip install Flask-HTMLmin