# error while installing pgadmin4 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to install pgadmin on ubuntu 18.04, but i'm getting following error. I also tried to rm and reinstall but it's getting same error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    pgadmin4-apache2 is already the newest version (4.25-1.pgdg18.04+1).
    pgadmin4 is already the newest version (4.29).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Setting up pgadmin4-apache2 (4.25-1.pgdg18.04+1) ...
    apache2_invoke pgadmin4: already enabled
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
        from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, \
      File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
    dpkg: error processing package pgadmin4-apache2 (--configure):
     installed pgadmin4-apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     pgadmin4-apache2
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried,

```
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

but its not working
plz anyone help me with this

Comment: Please check if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260004/error-trying-to-run-pgadmin4

Comment: no, getting same error again

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pgadmin.model import db, User, Version, ServerGroup, Server, \
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
dpkg: error processing package pgadmin4-apache2 (--configure):
 installed pgadmin4-apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pgadmin4-apache2

Comment: are you using this https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/ guide?