# Installing Python modules in version 3.5.2 with both Python 2.7 and 3.5 already installed on Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, module, beautifulsoup

I use both 2.7 and 3.5 and I want to keep both installed as we still use 2.7 in VFX and Gaming industry.

The problem is when I attempt to install a module in 3.5 (for this example, I'll use "pip3 install beautifulsoup4"), the module installs in the 2.7 folder and not 3.5 folder.

How do I get terminal to install the correct version of Python Module?

For the record I would like the modules to install in this folder:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

I've tried specifying the directory. I've heard running the "2to3 -w bs4" will convert the code to 3.5 for me but I am unfamiliar with this command so if anyone can correctly format it for me that would be greatly appreciated (I am still a newb so please be descriptive). Thank you!

Comment: You say the modules install in the 2.7 folder, but then you say "they install in this folder" and the folder you show says "python3.5".  Please clarify this.

Comment: Have you thought about using virtualenvs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)?

Comment: Hey @BrenBarn sorry for the confusion. What I mean't to say is I would like them to install in the python3.5 folder.

Comment: @jbndlr Virtualenv seems like overkill. I'm looking for a simple and quick solution right inside terminal. Many, many people use both 2.7 and 3.5 someone has to have come up with a solution for this by now. The "2to3 -w bs4" command works but is pretty involved.

Comment: @ThomasA, this is exactly what virtualenvs are designed for: manage different versions of python with different packages installed on the same machine. In your terminal just `workon yourenv` and `pip install yourpackage` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your `pip3` script. Does the `#!`-line at the beginning actually contain `python3.5`?

If not, change it.

Comment: I've tried both pip3 and pip3.5 - they both install to the 2.7 folder here: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: @ThomasA Read again.