# Different Python Installations

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Occasionally, when we install/update modules with pip other dependent modules stop working. Revert back the module version or to resolve the issues takes time. Due to the fact, working programs are also impacted. It would be really helpful to setup two different python environments, sandbox and production.

Would you please suggest how to maintain two python environments seamlessly from sandbox to production?

Comment: Any idea what [tag:virtualenv]s are?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+how+to+use