# beginner installing nosetests package

Tags: python, terminal, installation, nosetests

I'm trying to install the following as per the learnpythonthehardway tutorial:

1. pip from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip
2. distribute from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute
3. nose from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/
4. virtualenv from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

I've visited these links and clicked the download button; each file is in my downloads folder now, and I unarchive/unzipped them- not sure what this means but it seemed required. Are they "installed"? If not, what does it mean to really install them? I've tried typing `nosetests` in the terminal (as the book says you should), as well as tried `easy_install` but that doesn't seem to work. It appears my understanding is limited in a number of ways here.

I get the following `-bash: nosetests: command not found`, but am trying to get:

`nosetests . ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 0.007s
OK`

Comment: related: [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4324558/4279)

Answer (score 11):

This works on mac, it may work on linux

1)Open terminal (Be prepared to enter your password)

2)Type: `sudo easy_install pip`

3)Type: `sudo pip install distribute`

4)Type: `sudo pip install nose`

5)Type: `sudo pip install virtualenv`

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: for those who are following "learning python the hard way" this definitely works for mac

Comment: Please don't use sudo pip: https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for me. I have installed all of this required pieces, but still get message "-bash: nosetests: command not found"

I am in a directory with structure like this 

"dds-MacBook-Pro:skeleton ddsd$ ls -R
NAME  bin  docs  setup.py tests

./NAME:
__init__.py

./bin:

./docs:

./tests:
NAME_tests.py __init__.py"

I have double checked them: pip, distribute, nose, virtualenv and all of them are installed. Does anyone know what else can be done?

Comment: I found the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546228/installed-nose-but-cannot-use-on-command-line
Basically, after pip installing nose, easy_install nose.  Broken, yes, I would agree.

Answer (score 2):

They are not yet installed.
Each has its own vagaries about how exactly the install process works and in fact some of those packages will include the other packages with them. I.e.

> "If you use virtualenv, a copy of pip will be automatically be
>   installed in each virtual environment you create."
>
> http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

As a relatively new python user myself, (and having gone thru a similar process not long ago) I am eagerly awaiting the more complete answers that come back for this one.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like they are all interrelated in some way. I'm not sure where each package needs to be held on my computer, or if it matters. By typing `nosetest` in the terminal does that imply the package is in the right place, or just installed anywhere at all?

Comment: I believe it works more or less like this: 1) you download the package to some place on your computer 2) you perform the installation, often by issuing a terminal command that references the package you downloaded (or is issued from the same dir where the download is located). 3) After this point the installation process has copied the actual files to their proper spots on your computer and updates your path. 
After this you can remove the downloaded package. 
If nosetest is installed correctly, you will be able to type it at the prompt and get the response you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, but the package is actually called "nose". The documentation for nose (nosetests is the script) can be found here:
https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

The short answer is that you have 2 basic options: [easy_install](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-install-easy_install/) or [pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html). Install using setuptools/distribute: `easy_install nose`. Install using pip: `pip install nose`

Answer (score 1):

Find out where the nosetests script is. On OSX:

```
/usr/local/share/nosetests
```

Execute directly, or set up a bash alias, perhaps in .bash_profile:

```
alias nosetests='/usr/local/share/python/nosetests'
alias nosetests3='/usr/local/share/python3/nosetests'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 2.7 and after just do this (only on Windows - Windows PowerShell):

1. Setup PATH env:

> C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\", "User"

2. pip is already installed

3.

```
.\pip install distribute
```

4.

```
.\pip install nose
```

5.

```
.\pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: To me your answer is the most appropriate. Perhaps you need to explain each of the step and where exactly you type the commands. For example, a beginner will not know what to do with  your first step. You need to be explict and just say type the following in the Windows PowerShell:  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")