# Installed Nose but cannot use on command line

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, nose

I installed Nose on a Mac OSX 10.10.5 with Python2.7.9 using `easy_install`. The installation appeared to be successful:

```
Collecting nose
  Downloading nose-1.3.7-py2-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 155kB 2.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: nose
Successfully installed nose-1.3.7
```

But now, when I try even basic stuff with nosetests on the command line, like `nosetests -h` or `which nosetests` I just get:

```
bash: nosetests: command not found
```

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling using `pip`, tried installing with `sudo` and then running `sudo nostests` in the directories with tests scripts as other posts have suggested, but nothing seems to work.

The original purpose for installing was to use nose to run some basic tests with tests scripts I had written for these simple web.py apps. But nothing works, just keep getting the `command not found` response.

What's strange is that, when I open up the Python interpreter in Terminal, and do something like:

```
import nose 
nose.main()
```

I get the expected result of:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.135s

OK
```

So clearly it's installed....somewhere. Any suggestions for what the hell is going on here?

Comment: Try `nosetests-2.7`.

Comment: @RolandSmith Just tried `nosetests-2.7 -h` and still getting: `zsh: command not found: nosetests-2.7`

Comment: I think the `nosetests` command should be in `/usr/local/bin`. Is that part of your `$PATH` in `zsh`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On UNIX-like systems like OS X, the script *should* be in `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure that directory is in the `PATH` environment variable in the shell that you use.

If not, you can also locate it using `find`, e.g:

```
find / -type f -name 'nosetests*' -perm +111 -print -quit
```

This means; search for a file whose name starts with `nosetests`, which has execute permissions set. Print the path name and stop.

Comment: Thanks for that command, it seems to have returned:  `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/nosetests `  Knowing that, how should I adjust my approach to using Nosetests command?

Comment: Add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` to your `PATH`. How/where to do that depends on the shell you use.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there a workaround so that when I'm in a project directory I don't have to use this long file path to use Nosetests? Would setting PYTHONPATH= to something when I'm in the directory work?

Comment: When you are calling `nosetests` from a shell, it has nothing to do with `PYTHONPATH`. But all shells that I know of use an environment variable called`PATH` that contains a list of directories separated by colons. Shells look in these directories for executables. Any executable file in one of those directories can be started by just calling it by its name. Where to set this environment variable differs per shell. Look at FILES section in the manual page for your shell.

Answer (score 30):

There are lots of error occurred when using `pip` install packages on Mac OS. So I recommend you install `nose` using `easy_install`.

`$ pip uninstall nose`

`$ sudo easy_install nose`

Then you can try `nosetests` now :)

Answer (score 15):

I had this exact issue on OS X EI Captain with Python 2.7.10.

First I installed *nose* using *pip*:

```
$sudo pip install nose
```

which failed on the first attempt. Went through on the second attempt. But the  `nosetests` command didn't work.

In order to fix this:

Step 1: Don't uninstall *nose* if it was installed already using *pip* as in my case.

Step 2:

```
$cd /usr/bin

$sudo easy_install nose
```

Above command finds the nosetests script (which was installed by pip earlier) & sets it under `/usr/local/bin`

```
Step 3: Try nosetests

$nosetests

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.047s

OK
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that going to

```
Library/usr/bin
```

and running

```
sudo easy_install nose
```

it seems that sometimes it doesn't automatically install nose (and therefore nosetests functionality). Do the above lines, and you should be a-ok.

I wish i had a better explanation for why this happened, but i'm still pretty new, myself.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use

```
Nosetest
```

or

```
python3 -m "nose"
```

Apparently this is the way Nosetest should be used in Python3. See also
[How to make nosetests use python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114754/1117598)

Answer (score 0):

First, can you run 'python' from the command line? nosetests should be in that same directory:

```
rich bin $ which python
/home/rich/anaconda/bin/python
rich bin $ which nosetests
/home/rich/anaconda/bin/nosetests
```

It should also be in the downloaded nose package:

```
rich bin $ find /home/rich/anaconda -name nosetests
/home/rich/anaconda/pkgs/nose-1.3.3-py27_0/bin/nosetests
/home/rich/anaconda/pkgs/nose-1.3.7-py27_0/bin/nosetests
/home/rich/anaconda/bin/nosetests
```

Comment: Yes, I can definitely run python from the command line. When I run `which python` I get: `/usr/local/bin/python` but as I mentioned in my post, I can't run  `which nosetests`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, everyone is moving to [pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/) - an actively-maintained testing framework.

It's not a solution to *this* problem, but it's likely the most-appropriate choice if you are still using *nose*.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reinstall the pip, it doesn't work but lastly, when i use sudo ...it works

> pip3 uninstall nose
>
> sudo pip3 install nose

and

> which nosetests
>
> /usr/local/bin/nosetests

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you were running nose within a virtual environment, and that virtual environment has been deactivated. If this is the case, reactivate with `source bin/activate`.