# Setup.py---nosetests: command not found

Tags: python, nose, setup.py

I successfully installed nose on my laptop and try to run nosestest. However, terminal reminds me that:
"bash: nosetests: command not found."

What's strange is that, when I open up the Python interpreter in Terminal, and do something like:

```
import nose  
nose.main()
```

I get the expected result.

I tried to use

```
find / -type f -name 'nosetests*' -perm +111 -print -quit
```

from the answer [Installed Nose but cannot use on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546228/installed-nose-but-cannot-use-on-command-line/32546401). But the result pops out as:

```
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
```

FYI I'm following the steps of Learn Python the Hard Way.

THX

Comment: `which nosetests` will tell you if it is in the `PATH`

Comment: ty. I tried it but it does not return any result

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. How did you install the package?

Comment: does pip --version return something?

Comment: Credit is given to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546228/installed-nose-but-cannot-use-on-command-line/32546401 the reply which was answered Aug 5 '16 at 6:17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit is given to [Installed Nose but cannot use on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546228/installed-nose-but-cannot-use-on-command-line/32546401). the reply which was answered Aug 5 '16 at 6:17.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu (Unix) if you do a `pip install nose` it installs nose in this folder `/usr/local/bin`

to check this do `echo $PATH` for a unix system

it should you return a ":" separated list of folders. In this list of folders the folder with the nosetests executable needs to be for you to execute nosetests from the commandline

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me in python3.

I had to check for the file in `/usr/bin` directory using `locate nosetests` and discovered it's nosetests3.

Use `nosetests3` instead of `nosetests`.

```
$nosetests3
```

PS: You need to install locate,so as to use it for searching for files.

```
sudo apt install locate
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install locate
```