# installing matplotlib in a different default location

Tags: python, installation, matplotlib

In order to install matplotlib to a non default location, I change the file setup.cfg, setting the variable basedirlist.

I do

```
python setup.py build
```

and then

```
python setup.py install
```

but the last fail because:

```
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/colorbar.py -> /opt/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1
error: could not delete '/opt/python/2.6.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/colorbar.py': Read-only file system
```

I am not root, so how  can I install matplotlib? is there any other variable I have to set?

Comment: Could you use `easy_install`? This is what I used, try: `easy_install -a -U --install-dir non/default/directory`. Although be aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Comment: thanks, but then I should install easy_install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an unmodified version of `setup.cfg` and run `python setup.py install --help` There are several options for controlling where the files are installed, the important part of the help message being:

```
Options for 'install' command:
  --prefix            installation prefix
  --exec-prefix       (Unix only) prefix for platform-specific files
  --home              (Unix only) home directory to install under
  --user              install in user site-package
                      '/home/yannpaul/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages'
  --install-base      base installation directory (instead of --prefix or --
                      home)
```

Read over those options and choose which one suits you best.

I recommend, however, to use [`vertualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This sets up, in a directory of your choice, a custom library location and copy of python. All the other libraries (installed by a system admin for example) are available until you install your own copy of the library in this virtualenv.

Virtualenv is also a good option if you want to play around with the development version of a library, `matplotlib` for example. Setup a virtualenv for these development libraries, then use the python "executable" associated with that virtualenv to get access to the development version of the library.

Check out [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python) to get setup with virtualenv.