# requirements.txt depending on python version

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to port a python2 package to python3 (not my own) using six so that it's compatible with both.  However one of the packages listed in requirements.txt is now included in the python3 stdlib and the pypi version doesn't work in python3 so I want to conditionally exclude it.  Doing this in setup.py is easy, I can just do something like:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    requirements += py2_requirements
else:
    requirements += py3_requirements
```

But I would like requirements.txt to reflect the correct list too.  I can't find anything on this in the pip documentation. so does anyone know how to do it, or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You can use the [environment markers](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers) to achieve this in `requirements.txt` since `pip 6.0`:

```
SomeProject==5.4; python_version < '2.7'
SomeProject; sys_platform == 'win32'
```

It is supported by setuptools too by declaring extra requirements in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'six',
        'humanize',
    ],
    extras_require={
        ':python_version == "2.7"': [
            'ipaddress',
        ],
    },
)
```

See also [requirement specifiers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers).
And [Strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0496/#strings) for the string versions of corresponding Python commands.

Comment: Nice!  How can I do the same with `sys.platform == "win32"`?  I tried using `:sys.platform == "win32"`, but I get an "Invalid environment marker" error from the `setup()` function

Comment: Update: [PEP 496 -- Environment Markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/) has been superseded by [PEP 508 -- Dependency specification for Python Software Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/), which fully specifies the dependency declaration syntax including the [syntax for environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers).

Comment: This is great, but I feel that something has gone wrong if I need to use this? In the ideal world I guess the dependency should just itself declare that it requires Python < 2.7? Ok the OPs use case makes sense because the package actually moved location, but suppose we simply have the case that old versions don't work in Python 3. If I have control over the packages should I be going back and patching all the old versions to correctly specify their working upper Python bounds? What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 16):

You can create multiple requirements files, put those common packages in a common file, and include them in another pip requirements file with `-r file_path`

```
requirements/
  base.txt
  python2.txt
  python3.txt
```

python2.txt:

```
-r base.txt
Django==1.4 #python2 only packages
```

python3.txt:

```
-r base.txt
Django==1.5 #python3 only packages
```

pip install -r requirements/python2.txt