# Can I have a single Python requirements.txt file for multiple versions of Python?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

I'm just getting started with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on Windows 7.  I've created 3 different test projects using (respectively) Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5

I'd like to create a single requirements.txt file that installs the right binary lxml module for each version of Python.  That way I can run `pip install -r "C:\PyModules\requirements.txt"` on any virtualenv I may create. Following [an example listed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33451105/2510057) I tried a requirements.txt file like this:

```
C:\PyModules\lxml-3.5.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl; python_version == '2.7'
C:\PyModules\lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl; python_version == '3.4'
C:\PyModules\lxml-3.5.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl; python_version == '3.5'
```

But it didn't work.  Using this file with pip within a 2.7 environment gives:

```
lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

and trying it in my 3.4 environment gives:

```
lxml-3.5.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I had hoped the environment markers (python_version == '2.7') would cause pip to skip the lines entirely that referred to packages that were not intended for that Python version.  But it appears Python is ignoring the python_version marker when it examines the WHL files.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm wanting in a single requirements file?

**EDIT #1:** This is Windows 7 (64-bit), pip 7.1.2 and virtualenv 13.1.2

**EDIT #2:** As Sebastian suggested, I tried removing the quotes around the numbers in the requirements.txt file, which appears to be the right way to do it:

```
C:\PyModules\lxml-3.5.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl; python_version == 2.7
C:\PyModules\lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl; python_version == 3.4
C:\PyModules\lxml-3.5.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl; python_version == 3.5
```

But with a 2.7 environment, I now get this new error:

```
SyntaxError: don't know how to evaluate 'num' '2.7'
```

and in 3.4 it's still this error:

```
lxml-3.5.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: Are you sure you run 64-bit Windows and newest pip?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of pip is being used in each of the 3 environments?

Comment: pip 7.1.2 for all of them.