# installing numpy for python 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, ubuntu-10.04

I've searched everywhere I could and I couldn't find appropriate answer. I don't know how to install numpy so I could use it in Geany with python 3.1.2. It only works for python 2.6.5. I'm new to ubuntu.

edit: I get ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: I believe http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com/ would be better places to ask. Anyway, you'll have to provide more detail. What is it that goes wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I will ask there too.

Answer (score 2):

If `python 3.1.2` is installed via `python3` package then you could try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Comment: I get "Couldn't find package python3-numpy". And from what I have read about this it's not that simple.

Comment: @malganis: It is that simple on 12.04. To experiment create a vurtualenv (using python3 binary) and run: `pip install numpy` inside the environment (I do it to install recent numpy versions). You might need to install dependencies before it. A simple way to do it is to run: `sudo apt-get build-dep python-numpy`.

Comment: "To experiment create a virtualenv (using python3 binary) and run: pip install numpy inside the environment (I do it to install recent numpy versions)"  What exactly do you mean by that? I put this into terminal and I get "The program 'pip' can be found in the following packages:
 * pip
 * python-pip
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>"
I have installed dependancies.

Comment: Would it work if I install it from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files? The problem is then I don't know how to install from tar files. If it is not step by step I get lost.

Comment: @malganis: here's [step-by-step instruction on how to install and create a vurtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5177027/4279) (choose a more recent virtualenv version and use the path to python3). Use only pip that is installed inside your environment, don't try to install using system pip. `pip` automatically downloads necessary files, builds and installs them (it takes a while for numpy).

Answer (score 0):

Tried the apt-get installation solution above but it didn't work, *however*, pip did work:

```
$ sudo pip3 install numpy
```

Also, here are the [install instructions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) for pip if needed.