# Installing Python setup tools on Unix to run Tweepy Twitter client for Python

Tags: python, unix, installation, tweepy

I am trying to run Tweepy client for Twitter on my Unix account. whenever i try to run setup for Tweepy using the command:

```
python setup.py
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 3, in ?
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Now i searched on some forums and found i need to add setup tools file. The file i found

```
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

I FTP - ed this file to my unix directory where i have Tweepy client directory and my program which is using Tweepy.

Now, whenever i try to install setup tools using the command

```
python setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
```

I get the error :

```
python setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
  File "setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg", line 2
    if [ `basename $0` = "setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg" ]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any clues/suggestions what i must be doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use setuptools, use [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/). Setuptools is old and deprecated. Until python 3.4 with packaging/distutils2 is around use distribute, which is a fork of old setuptools/distutils.

Simply download the distribute source tarball, unpack and run `python setup.py install`. Alternatively, you can download [distribute-setup.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/#distribute-setup-py) and just run it.

Answer (score 1):

To install `tweepy`, run inside a virtualenv:

```
(venv) $ pip install tweepy
```

To create a virtual environment and install setuptools/distribute/easy_install, pip, and virtualenv, run:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
$ python virtualenv.py venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
```

<sup>[taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946537)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The setuptools [documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other) suggest using `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` instead of `python setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg`.

You get a `SyntaxError` from python because setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg begins as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ `basename $0` = "setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg" ]
then exec python2.7 -c "import sys, os; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('$0')); from setuptools.command.easy_install import bootstrap; sys.exit(bootstrap())" "$@"
else
  echo $0 is not the correct name for this egg file.
  echo Please rename it back to setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg and try again.
  exec false
fi
PK\00\00\00\00F\A3\E...
```

Comment: @CodeMonkey, you can update your question with additional info/error message if you are still trying to make `setuptools` work.