# ImportError: No module named bs4 because in wrong python folder

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. I am just trying to extract a string from an HTML file.
I cannot make it work. Everyone is talking about Beautiful Soup but it doesn't work for me...

This is my error:

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I installed Beautiful Soup 4 already but I believe it is in the wrong folder:

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I am using Python 3.2. How do I force Beautiful Soup to install in the other folder?

Comment: Use the Python 3.2 `pip`; each `pip` installation is tied to *one* Python version.

Comment: Related / possible dupe: [Pip install for both pythons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16129720)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install python3 version of package via pip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763440/how-to-install-python3-version-of-package-via-pip)

Answer (score 1):

Look, I suggest you download first the package of BeautifulSoup from its source in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup, once this has completed go to the folder where you download the compressed file , decompress the file and then inside you will see a python file named **setup.py**. This is the install file of the package, you need to run a command prompt in the folder and execute teh following line :

**python setup.py install**

This is another way of install Python packages without **pip**.