# Using virtualenv on machine without access to pypi

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to install a virtual environment with a few packages on an Ubuntu Server 10.04, but when I try to create the virtual environment, I get an error saying that it can't reach pypi to install distribute.

The machine can access apt, but not much else, and I would like to keep the amount of global packages to a minimum. I can also bring in Python packages manually, which was the plan once I have the virtual environment going.

The machine has python-setuptools, python-pip, python-virtualenv installed.

How can I use virtualenv on a machine that is offline or close to it?

Comment: Did you apt-get install python-pip? can you show us the error message?

Comment: Did you see virtualenv's installation page? -> http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#installation

Comment: @AlbertoMegía I have a dump of the output here: http://bpaste.net/show/vvcMD2jzLAub3XT9Uw04/ and yes I have python-pip installed.

Comment: @AlbertoMegía I have looked at the docs, yes, but I'm not sure what part of it addresses my issue.

Comment: tbh, I don't know exactly why, but your virtualenv creation is failing on the download of Distribute.  as a workaround, you can try:
passing the "--setuptools" option to virtualenv, or manually installing Distribute globally on the machine.  this should all work fine using the latest virtualenv/pip/setuptools.

Comment: Ok! it looks like you did not download distribute correctly, so when it tries to create the environment and check requirements it fails. I will try to reproduce it

Answer (score 3):

Going through virtualenv.py source codes, we can see it uses pip to install setuptools/pip/wheel when creating venv. So we can utilize the offline installation options provided in pip, through:

```
# --extra-search-dir can be set multiple times, then it produces a list
virtualenv --extra-search-dir path/to/setuptoolsPackages --no-download venv
```

A complete example

```
# Download pip, setuptools and wheel package to current dir.
ls
# argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl  setuptools-20.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

# Offline version.
# Set extra-search-dir to current dir.
time virtualenv --extra-search-dir ${PWD} --no-download venv
# New python executable in /home/me/wcftest/venv/bin/python3.5
# Also creating executable in /home/me/wcftest/venv/bin/python
# Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
# 
# real  0m3.670s
# user  0m1.350s
# sys   0m0.161s

# On-line.
time virtualenv venv2
# New python executable in /home/me/wcftest/venv2/bin/python3.5
# Also creating executable in /home/me/wcftest/venv2/bin/python
# Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
# 
# real  0m8.419s
# user  0m1.624s
# sys   0m0.179s
```

See [this blog](http://www.wangchaofeng.com/parseNote.php?note=notes_programming_python_virtualenv.note#toc-how-to-create-venv-offline) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found in this SO question: [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python)

I followed the suggestion by Walker Hale IV and it worked fine. Please close as duplicate.