# virtualenv error: "'.../bin/easy_install' not found"

Tags: python, virtualenv

using python3.3 on OS X 10.7.5

when i run

```
virtualenv-3.3 virtualenv/
```

it errors on

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.../virtualenv/bin/easy_install'
```

after

```
Overwriting virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site.py with new content
Overwriting virtualenv/lib/python3.3/orig-prefix.txt with new content
Overwriting virtualenv/lib/python3.3/no-global-site-packages.txt with new content
New python executable in virtualenv/bin/python3.3
Not overwriting existing python script virtualenv/bin/python (you must use virtualenv/bin/python3.3)
Overwriting virtualenv/lib/python3.3/distutils/__init__.py with new content
File virtualenv/lib/python3.3/distutils/distutils.cfg exists with different content; not overwriting
Installing distribute...done.
Installing pip...
```

my system has `setuptools` / `distribute`.

why isn't `virtualenv` setting up `easy_install`?

Comment: There seems to be an issue on github about this:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/281

Do you have the latest version of virtualenv?

Comment: yes, i set it up today (virtualenv 1.10.1)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to having an outdated version of Pip, I think.

I got a similar error on CEntOS 6.3.

I suggest at least attempting to bootstrap a virtual environment. If it doesn't work, all you have to lose are some megabytes and a 20 minutes of your time.

What you will need:

- Compiled Python3.4
- Source of the latest VirtualEnv
- Fortitude
- Pen and paper

Something similar to the answer outlined here might work: [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python)

In short, download the [virtualenv package from source](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#downloads), extract it, and cd into the directory created by the extraction.

From the documentation:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz 
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
```

Replace the X.X above with the version number. For example, `cd virtualenv-X.X` would, after replacing the Xs with the right version number, be `cd virtualenv-13.1.2`.

Then, use `virtualenv.py` from *there*, not just `$ virtualenv`, but `$ ./virtualenv.py`.

I hope that this would work much better, since pip with the latest virtualenv will include easy_install in the expected location.

I have tested this on a CEntOS 6.3 machine with a similar configuration. It works on there, but I cannot afford a copy of OS X 10.7.5.