# How can I install pip portably on a usb drive?

Tags: python, git, bash, pip

I'm trying to install pip on a usb drive F: next to portable python, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using Git-bash (msys) as my command line. Please see below for my attempts:

```
MYPC /f
$ which python
/f/ppython275/App/python    

MYPC /f
$ which pip    

MYPC /f
$ python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Downloading pip-1.5.tar.gz (898kB): 898kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pip    

    warning: no files found matching 'pip\cacert.pem'
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build\_sources'
Installing collected packages: pip
  Running setup.py install for pip    

    warning: no files found matching 'pip\cacert.pem'
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs\_build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build\_sources'
    Installing pip-script.py script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip.exe script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip.exe.manifest script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip2.7-script.py script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip2.7.exe script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip2.7.exe.manifest script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip2-script.py script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip2.exe script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
    Installing pip2.exe.manifest script to f:\ppython275\App\Scripts
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...    

MYPC /f
$ which pip
```

I've restarted the command line. but "which pip" still yields nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: is `f:\ppython275\App\Scripts` in your `PATH`?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your `$PATH` environment variable to add `/f/ppython275/App/Scripts`, so the shell looks in that directory for executables.

Edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and add the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/f/ppython275/App/Scripts
```

Save, restart your shell, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks MattDMo, that worked! As a quick follow up : Is there a way to put the .bashrc on my F drive , so as to make everything truly portable? Thanks again - Bill