# How to install packages for the custom installed python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3. By default it is bundled with Python 2.6.6.

However I need to have Python 2.7.6. So performed an alternative custom install using the following steps:

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7..tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.7.6.tgz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure
make altinstall
```

All went find and I got the Python-2.7.6 installed properly. For example,

```
[root@nc9037034032 Python-2.7.6]# python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.6
```

Now I need to install additional packages for the Python 2.7.6. For example, I need to install requests library for this python 2.7.6.

How to do this? I am familiar with installing packages in python using pip, easy_install,..... However they are installing in the old python i.e. 2.6.6. How to do it for the newly custom installed python?

Comment: You need to install the distribute or setup packages for python2.7 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python?rq=1

Comment: Sounds like [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/) is something you wanna look into.

Comment: dont think the answer is given in that SO answer. My situation is different here as I have two python version in the same box.