# How to set the correct $PATH to PIP, VIRTUALENV and NOSETESTS

Tags: python, path, pip, virtualenv, nosetests

On my `Mac OSX 10.9.2`, my default python is now `Python 2.7.6`, which was upgraded form `2.5.4`, the previous sys installation.

I have `pip 1.5.4 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)` and `virtualenv --version 1.11.4` both installed at `~/bin`, and which virtualenv and which pip return `./bin/pip` and `./bin/virtualenv`

which python returns: `/usr/local/bin/python`

```
sys.path:

['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/projectname-0.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

`~/bin` has:

```
Vitors-MacBook-Pro:bin vitorpatalano$ ls -lha
total 328
drwxr-xr-x  16 vitorpatalano  staff   544B Apr 13 21:57 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 31 vitorpatalano  staff   1.0K Apr 17 11:06 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 vitorpatalano  staff   6.0K Apr  6 01:28 .DS_Store
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   232B Apr  6 23:45 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   232B Apr  6 23:45 easy_install-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 vitorpatalano  staff    76K Apr 10 23:26 mate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   373B Apr  7 00:07 nosetests
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   381B Apr  7 00:07 nosetests-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   241B Apr  6 01:29 pip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   243B Apr  6 01:29 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   247B Apr  6 01:29 pip2.7
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   211B Apr  6 22:46 virtualenv
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   211B Apr  6 22:46 virtualenv-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   346B Apr 13 21:57 virtualenv-clone
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff    36K Apr 13 21:56 virtualenvwrapper.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           staff   1.4K Apr 13 21:56 virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

my `.bash_profile` has:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=./bin:$PATH
```

PROBLEMS:

1. pip runs only at `~/`, and requires `sudo`
2. inside activated virtualenv, pip is not at, say, `ENV/bin` but at `ENV/lib` and runs GLOBALLY, installing packages at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

3.outside `~/bin`, virtualenv runs only if I type `python -m virtualenv venv`

1. nosetests runs only with `nosetests -w /path/to/dir`

looks like I have to bypass sys.

QUESTIONS:

1. how do I reconfigure `$PATH` in order to have `virtualenv, pip and nosetests` working at ANY given directory, without the need for `sudo`?
2. how to have pip within virtualenv installing packages INSIDE the environment?

Comment: please check the following:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python

Comment: thanks, I had already checked this link. didn't find my answers there, though. my questions concern (re-)configuration of PATHs rather than installing pip and virtualenv. what's really bothering me is how to make pip install locally within virtualenv and not globally.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but have you *activated* the virtual env? I think it gets activated by default when you create it, but if you close the window or log out or whatever, you'll need to reactivate it. So try: `. ./path/to/virtual/env/bin/activate` (note that there are two dots in that command, separated by a space)