# linux switch between ananconda python 3.4 and 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, anaconda

I do most of my work in Python 2.7, but I've recently encountered some tutorials that require 3.4.  Fine.  I checked and Anaconda allows installation of both under Linux (Fedora 22 to be precise).  However, now I seem to be stuck in 3.4.  I followed the Anaconda directions, entering:

`conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda
source activate py3k`

I would like to be able to choose between 2.7 and 3.4 each time I run Python.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error?

Comment: `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` - `source activate py27`? :)

Comment: my answer here may be more detailed on how to make effective use of conda environments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708882/how-to-install-python-libraries-under-specific-environments/27712027#27712027

Comment: I'm afraid the question is much more simple:  As I said above, I started with a standard install of 2.7.  I activated py3k, the name I gave the 3.4 installation.  What is the command to close that version and activate 2.7??

Comment: You can give alias to launch different python versions. eg. defaullt python will be in `/usr/lib/python` or `/usr/lib/python2.7`. Give an alias to this and give another alias to anaconda version. I have done it that way in my computer. You dont have to use environments. In that way it is cleaner. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question. Python 2.7 seems to be the default.  If I activate 3.x with 

`source activate py3k`

I need to reboot to go back to 2.7, which, being the default, happens automatically.

If anyone knows a cleaner way, please let me know.

Comment: OK, when I was installing 3.x on another computer I saw a message I had missed during the first install: ```To deactivate this environment, use:
$ source deactivate.  ```