# Python:Command not found virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv using the command `pip install virtualenv` and it gave me this.

```
pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB):   0%   Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB):   0%    Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB): 1.8MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

Now you can see that virtualenv is installed to confirm this i have tested like this,

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  which pip
/usr/bin/pip
 ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  which python
/usr/bin/python
 ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  which virtualenv
virtualenv not found
 ✘ ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  python --version
Python 2.7.12
ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Now real problem is that i want to create a virtualenv i have entered command

`virtualenv env --no-site-packages` and it gave me error.

```
command not found: virtualenv
```

Any solutions to this problem.I have also using ubuntu -16 with all updates installed.

Comment: The executable of `virtualenv` seems not to be in the load-path. Just reopening the terminal might already help, otherwise `pip show virtualenv` shows you the location that you can then add to your load-path.

Comment: `ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  pip show virtualenv
---
Name: virtualenv
Version: 15.1.0
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: 
 ubuntu@ubuntu  ~  virtualenv      
zsh: command not found: virtualenv
`

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: You should never install using `pip` in your Linux systems' python, you might break your system. Apart from that the current `pip` version is 9.0.1, that what you have there is outdated and insecure. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30692103/1307905 on how to properly create and use `virtualenv` in a virtual env.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use your system's package manger to install it instead of pip. On Ubuntu, you can run:

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

You will then see output from the 'which' command.

Comment: In addition to this correct answer: `/usr/bin/pip` could not install virtualenv into system directories because regular user "ubuntu" cannot write into `/usr/bin/`. Then virtualenv was installed into user install directory, so you can launch it as `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/virtualenv`. Optionally, append `~/.local/bin` to `$PATH`.

Comment: This might work but should not be recommended. Installing this way gives you virtualenv 1.11. The current version of virtualenv is 15.1, which has many bug fixes, and works with a more modern versions of `pip` for further installs (with their own bug and security fixes). Since you can install virtualenv directly in a virtualenv without needing root prileges, the normal excuse that you should not litter your installation with non-tracked data doesn't hold.

Comment: @Anthon it looks like 15.1 is available in the Ubuntu 16 repos http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python-virtualenv

Comment: Correction - 15.0.1