# bash: virtualenv: command not found "ON Linux"

Tags: python, linux, pip, virtualenv, apt-get

I am using a form of Lubuntu called GalliumOS (optimized for Chromebooks).  I installed pip using `$ sudo apt-get install python-pip`. I then used `pip install --user virtualenv` and `pip install virtualenv`, and then when I tried to subsequently use `virtualenv venv` I experienced the message `bash: virtualenv: command not found`.

Between the pip installs above, I used `pip uninstall virtualenv` to get back to square one. The error remained after a reinstall.

I read several other posts, but all of them seemed to deal with similar problems on MacOS. One that came close was installing python pip and virtualenv simultaneously. Since I had already installed pip, I didn't think that these quite applied to my issue. Why is `pip install virtualenv`  not working this way on LUbuntu / GalliumOS?

Comment: If you want to post a question to which you already have the answer, you should post just the question in the "Question" box and put the answer separately in the "Answer" box.  Otherwise, your question isn't a question.

Comment: @thom-ives Please post your answer as an answer, so that someone else, whose time will be saved, can upvote it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4324558/608639). Also see [Differences between distribute, distutils, setuptools and distutils2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753678/608639)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python)

Comment: Thanks guys for clarifying the best way to post in these cases. I will seek to clarify as you've suggested OR delete my post.

Comment: When you do `sudo pip install virtualenv`, what directory is `virtualenv` installed to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally worked for me was this. I used

`$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`.

I was then able to create a virtual environment using `$ virtualenv venv`.

I was seeking to avoid using `$ sudo pip install virtualenv`, because of admonitions in other posts to not do this, and agreed, because of experiences I'd had with subsequent difficulties when doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `pip install` is "failing"? To me, it sounds like the directory to which `pip` is installing modules on your machine is not in your `PATH` environment variable, so when `virtualenv` is installed, your computer has no idea where to find it when you just type in `virtualenv`.

Find where `pip` is installing things on your computer, and then check if the directory where the `pyenv` executable is placed is in your `PATH` variable (e.g. by doing `echo $PATH` to print your `PATH` variable). If it's not, you need to update your `PATH` variable by adding the following to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or etc.:

`export PATH="PATH_TO_WHERE_PIP_PUTS_EXECUTABLES:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install virtualenv
```

This command worked for me for. This problem that raised to me on Kali Linux.