# Why should I install Python packages into `~/.local`?

Tags: python

### Background

1. I don't develop using OS X's system provided Python versions (on  OS X 10.6 that's Python 2.5.4 and 2.6.1).
2. I don't install anything in the site-packages directory for the OS provided versions of Python. (The only exception is Mercurial installed from a binary package, which installs two packages in the Python 2.6.1 site-packages directory.)
3. I installed three versions of Python, all using the Mac OS X installer disk image:

   1. Python 2.6.6
   2. Python 2.7
   3. Python 3.1.2
4. I don't like polluting the site-packages directory for my Python installations. So I only install the following five base packages in the site-packages directory. For the actual method/commands used to install these, see [SO Question 4324558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/).

   1. [setuptools/ez_setup](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall)
   2. [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/)
   3. [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/)
   4. [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/)
   5. [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/)
5. All other packages are installed in virtualenvs.
6. I am the only user of this MacBook.

### Questions

1. Given the above background, why should I install the five base packages in `~/.local`? Since I'm installing these base packages into the site-packages directories of Python distributions that I've installed, I'm isolated from the OS X's Python distributions.
2. Using this method, should I be concerned about Glyph's comment that other things could potentially break (see his comment below)?

Again, I'm only interested in where to install those five base packages.

### Related Questions/Info

I'm asking because of [Glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13564/glyph)'s comment to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314376/python-egg-file/4314446#4314446) to [SO question 4314376](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314376/), which stated:

> NO. NEVER EVER do `sudo python setup.py install` whatever. Write a ~/.pydistutils.cfg that puts your pip installation into ~/.local or something. Especially files named `ez_setup.py` tend to suck down newer versions of things like setuptools and easy_install, which can potentially break other things on your operating system.

Previously, I asked [What's the proper way to install pip, virtualenv, and distribute for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/). However, no one answered the "why" of using `~/.local`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no particularly good reason for or against installing in `.local` for Mac OS X installations using framework builds.  There is still some controversy among Python core developers on this point with Glyph arguing that the `.local` location, introduced in Python 2.6 for other *Unixy* systems, should be used for Mac OS X and simplifies third-party installation processes, while others argue that the previous traditional locations for Mac OS X framework builds is more natural.  In the end, it is up to you. Particularly if you are using virtual environments, if it works, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, I do not think it is a good idea to install Python packages into `.local`, but to use `virtualenv` to create a separate environment for each package.

**My reason**

While installations into `.local` do not interfere with the system wide Python, you still can have conflicts between several packages installed into `.local`.

P.S.: If you do you like `virtualenv` you could also use `pipx`.